# Lightning:Datable returns blank

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, wrapper-class

I am using a wrapper class in generating the values for a lightning:datatable, however no value is being rendered on the table.

Apex Class:

```
public class wrapperObject{
    @auraEnabled
    public String Name;
    @auraEnabled
    public Integer Days;        
    public wrapperObject(){}
}
    
@auraEnabled
public static List<wrapperObject> getSequence(String param){
    List<wrapperObject> oList= new List<wrapperobject>();
    for(Account a : [SELECT id, Name, somefield__c from Account where somefield__c =: param]){
        wrapperObject w = new wrapperObject();
        w.Name = a.Name;
        w.Days= Integer.valueOf(a.somefield__c);
        oList.add(w);
    }
    return oList;
}
```

Component

```
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.oList}" columns="{!v.oColumns}" keyField="id" 
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true" column-widths-mode="auto"/>
```

JSController

```
loadCadenceSequence : function(component, event, helper){
    component.set('v.oColumns', [          
        {label: 'Sequence Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}, 
        {label: 'Days From Previous Sequence', fieldName: 'Days', type: 'number'}
    ]);         
     var action = component.get("c.getSequence");
     action.setParams({param:component.get("v.param")});
     action.setCallback(this, function(response){               
     component.set("v.oList", response.getReturnValue());            
     });        
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

I am using a wrapper class because there are other field columns that i need to return which will be computed based from param.

Answer (score 1):

While there are multiple possible explanations (do you see any console logs, for example?) the immediate problem I see in the code presented is that your `keyField` does not exist on your data records:

```
keyField="id"
```

as your wrapper class does not have an `id` field. Assuming `Name` is unique in this data set, you should probably be using `Name` as your `keyField`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, there are console logs. I figured out the problem, my oList is returning 'Days', 'Name'. And my column is 'Name' 'Days'. After changing my column to 'Days' 'Name', the data rendered as expected.

Comment: I don't think that could have possibly fixed it. The order of the data does not matter. It must be something else.

Comment: Agreed with Caspar. Maps aren't ordered collections, so that should make no difference.